# What is the use of Web2py's Field.Method?

Tags: python, web2py

I wanted to know what does the - `Field.Method` means/ What is the use of this function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically a calculated db field. From the book:

> It is also possible to define method fields which are calculated
>   on-demand, when called. For example:
>
> > > > db.item.discounted_total = Field.Method(lambda row, discount=0.0:        row.item.unit_price*row.item.quantity*(1.0-discount/100))
>
> In this case row.discounted_total is not a value but a function. The
>   function takes the same arguments as the function passed to the Method
>   constructor except for row which is implicit (think of it as self for
>   rows objects).

http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer?search=Field.Method